# Create Observable that displays once or updates without duplication

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic-framework, ionic2

I'm making an Ionic app with geolocation, the geolocation is handled by the Firebase Geofire library handling all the Havershine formula (geo location) calculations.

Ive reworked the following to work with typescript (http://jsfiddle.net/katowulf/9GEFf/), basically it merges 2 firebase tables/collections (theres more than 2 being joined but leaving them out for brevity) and my desired result is to feed these to my homepage component to show all users that are close by.

I understand most concepts of Angular but ill admit i struggle with executing Observables and RxJS as a whole successfully, either my attempts duplicate data in the array, or when a value gets updated it duplicates in the view etc or else it simply doesnt work - Ive come across these scenarios multiple times so I think this could help out a lot of people if a pro angular guy can shed some light on this..

My first function listusers gets the current active users lattitude/long and feeds that to a geoFire query which iterates over the database gathering any other latt/long that are within a 20 mile radius.

This then feeds those user ids one at a time to the loadUser function which specifies the tables to join etc and and then it executes the joinPaths function which is where the data gathering and object merging magic happens...

This then outputs the data to  this.show(mergedObject) which is where I would like to be able to grab my data from in the template but I'm unsure how to do this, Ive tried Observable.of, Observable.from etc but either the data doesnt display in my template or like I mentioned before it duplicates the data...

any genius out there have any ideas on how to get this working flawlessly ? Its literally the one thing that holds me back with apps.

I think that because this iterates over each user thats nearby that this could cause issues with observables - what i need is something which gathers all the results and when it has done that create an array that can be fed to my home component, I'm happy to not have this list update in real time at this stage, its probably better from a UX perspective anyway to let the users pull to update as they wish.

// my service component

```
    public joinPaths(id, paths, callback) {
        let returnCount = 0;
        let expectedCount = paths.length;
        let mergedObject = {};
        paths.forEach( (p) => {
            this.fb().database().ref(p).child(id).once('value',
                // success
                 (snap) => {

                    this.extendObj(mergedObject, snap.val());

                    if (++returnCount === expectedCount) {
                        this.show(mergedObject);
                    }
                },
                (error) => {
                    returnCount = expectedCount + 1; // abort counters
                    console.log( "error in joinPaths ", error );
                }
            );
        });
    }

    public loadUser(userId) {
        this.joinPaths(userId, ['users', 'geofire'], this.show);
    }

    public show(obj?): Observable<any> {
       return Observable.of( obj );
    }

    public listUsers() {    
        this.fb().database().ref(`/users/${this.userID}/lastKnownLocation`).once('value').then( (snapshot) => {     
            this.geoFire.query({ center: [snapshot.val().lat, snapshot.val().lng], radius: 20  }).on( "key_entered", (key, location, distance) => {
                this.loadUser(key);
            });
        });       
    }


    // merge the tables data into one object
    private extendObj<T1,T2>(objA: T1, objB: T2) {
        for(let key in objB){
            if(objB.hasOwnProperty(key)){
                (objA as any)[key] = (objB as any)[key];
            }
        }    
        return <T1&T2>objA;
    }
```

// my home.ts

```
import { Component, NgZone } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController, PopoverController } from 'ionic-angular';
import { geoApi } from '../../providers/geo';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { Storage } from '@ionic/storage';

@Component({
  selector: 'page-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.html'
})
export class HomePage {

public users$: Observable<any>;

  constructor( public _api: geoApi ) {                                       
          this._api.listUsers();
          this.users$ = this._api.show();
    }


}
```

// home.html

```
    <ion-header>
        <ion-navbar>
            <ion-title>Home</ion-title>
        </ion-navbar>
    </ion-header>

    <ion-content padding>

    <ion-grid>    
        <ion-col *ngFor="let c of users$" class="member-item" tappable width-33>                          
            <ul class="o-list-reset c--user">
                <li class="c-username o-center c-uname">{{ c?.firstName }}</li>
            </ul>
        </ion-col>     
    </ion-grid>  

    </ion-content>
```

and on each iteration of these functions a users data similar to the following is fed to the final function show()

```
    {
        // geofire table/collection data merged
        "g": "u2fkbvz3rk",
        "l": [
            51.085535799999995,
            13.457294699999998
        ],
        // users table/collection data merged
        "profile": {
            "about": {
            "avatarUrl": "assets/img/generic.png",
            "birthday": "2015-01-01",
            "blockedBy": "",
            "email": "janek@gmail.com",
            "firstName": "Janek",
            "gender": "female",
            "id": "yrdUxr1dlmOyPJ6kcD2ss55gfd4",
            "isDeleted": 0,
            "isFacebookLinked": "",
            "isVerified": 0,
            "lastKnownLocation": {
                "lat": 51.085535799999995,
                "lng": 13.457294699999998
            },        
            },
        }
```

Comment: Maybe you should async pipe since you are directly binding an observable to ngfor. ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42856913/observable-and-ngfor-in-angular-2?